# Sending Json string to .asmx web service causing HTTP 500

Tags: android, json, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to send parameters to my web service which offers both XML and JSON depending on the request type in header. However, when i pass the JSON parameters, the servers responds me back with Status Code **500**.

Here's the method I'm calling on my web service:

```
[WebMethod]
public string EchoEmployee(Employee emp)
{
    return "you sent employee " + emp.Name;
}
```

*`Employee` is a test class which contains a couple of string and int fields

the JSON string which I'm passing to the webservice method:

```
{"emp":[{"Name":"Waqas Aslam","Company":"Dell"}]}
```

If I look into the xml structure of my method, this is how it explains:

```
<EchoEmployee xmlns="TestIntegrationLayer">
      <emp>
        <Id>int</Id>
        <Name>string</Name>
        <Company>string</Company>
        <Address>string</Address>
        <Phone>string</Phone>
        <Country>string</Country>
        <DOB>dateTime</DOB>
      </emp>
</EchoEmployee>
```

I know I'm setting only two keys in my JSON string, but does it matter? Should I need to define all the keys? What else could be wrong in my JSON string?

Comment: why emp in your json is an array?

Comment: yes, i realized it and removed `[]`, and it worked! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I added the following to my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" 
             preCondition="integratedMode" 
             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Also make sure that your service is a **ScriptService** by decorating the class like this:

```
[ScriptService]
public class SomeService : BaseWebService
{
}
```

I had to remove the **WebService** decoration.